# Problemas con borrado en base de datos desde php

Tags: php, mysql

He creado un botón el cual borra la linea la cual pertenece y funciona correctamente, el problema es el siguiente:

Cuando yo añado una linea, el boton de añadir linea me envia a la pagina de las tablas, si yo actualizo la pagina con ctrl+f5 no sucede nada, se queda igual.

Pero, si borro una linea desde el boton, se borra la linea, pero cada vez que refresco la pagina se borra otra linea como si el boton se quedase pillado, que puede suceder.

Aqui la pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de la tabla y del boton:

clientes.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['borrar_linea_automocion'])){
    Conexion::abrir_conexion();

    $linea=RepositorioEconomia::obtener_economia_personal(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $dni);
    $prueba = $linea[0];
    $prueba = $prueba['id_factura'];
    RepositorioEconomia::borrar_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(),$prueba);

    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
}
?>
div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <h5>Economia:</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="añadir-economia.php"><button type="button" class="btn-abrir-modal align-right"
                                    data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#AñadirEconomia">
                                    Añadir Linea
                                </button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    Conexion::abrir_conexion();
                    $ob_eco=RepositorioEconomia::obtener_economia_personal(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $dni);
                    EscritorioEconomia::escribir_entradas($ob_eco);
                    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
                   ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

EscritorioEconomia:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="borrar_linea_automocion" value="<?php $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-basura" value="X">
</form>
```

Comment: El problema lo tienes aquí:  `if (isset($_POST['borrar_linea_automocion'])){` pues al hacer F5 lo vuelves a mandar, y no veo que compruebes el valor de ese POST, pues simplemente lo usas como disparador de lo que viene despues que nada tiene que ver.  Yo de ti verificaria si el id_factura enviado en el POST del name `borrar_linea_automocion` aun existe antes de borrar nada.

Comment: TIenes razon, lo investigo y actualizo cuando lo tenga. No me di cuenta.

Comment: Primeramente me he dado cuenta de que la linea la borra mal por que borra la primera linea asi que voy a seguir investigando.